# How to force landscape mode and show the screen only in landscape mode?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have done all the below things, but the screen still auto rotates to portrait.

Correction: To make it clear, I need just one of the screens to go landscape and stay landscape only. The rest of them can orient with the device

```
    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        WillAnimateRotation(UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft, 0.0);

        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
    }
    public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
    {

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape;
    }

    public override UIInterfaceOrientation PreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation()
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
    }
    public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your either the Project Options dialog, or in the info.plist editor, you can select which device orientations your app supports.

[image]

Comment: I need just one of the screens to go landscape and stay landscape only. The rest of them can orient with the device